# How topass AJAX variables to another JS function

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Hi everyone I am currently developing a catalog and I manage user comments on products which works well, but I have now decided to use AJAX to do it but unfortunately I am new to AJAX and it creates a bit of trouble for me for the moment. I would like to pass the 'id' and 'pageNumber' variables to the getReviews () function so that it can use them in the url

HTML

```
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a class='page-link is-active' data-id=".$prodId." data-link=".$counter.">$counter</a></li>";
    <li><a class='page-link' href='$ver=$counter' data-id=".$prodId." data-link=".$counter.">$counter</a></li>";
</ul>
 
<div id='display_reviews' class="col-md-7"></div>
</body>
```

AJAX

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
getReviews();
 
$(document).on('click', '.paging li a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var pageNumber = $(this).data('link');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/mysite/product/?action=getProductReviews&id='+id+'&page='+pageNumber,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                getReviews();
            }
        });
    });
 
function getReviews(){
                $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/mysite/product/?action=getProductReviews&id='+id+'&page='+pageNumber,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                    $('#display_reviews').html(response);
            }
        });
};
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Like: `getReviews(id, pageNumber);` and `function getReviews(id, pageNumber){...` now you can access within the function.

Comment: You seem to be requesting the correct product reviews, then when it completes, you call `getReviews()` to load them _again_ (this time without `id` and `pageNumber`). Why do it twice. Can't you just place the `$('#display_reviews').html(response);` inside the success callback and remove the `getReviews()` function entirely?

Comment: @Ivar, thanks for your answer but decided to do it so cause the first one is the clickable event, means that there must be an ouput first before it can be clickable, that the role calling getReviews() function